# Finding and showing that the inverse of a transition map is smooth

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, diffeomorphism

I'm trying to show that stereographic projection from the north and south pole determine a smooth atlas, and I just showed that the transition map
$$
\varphi_N\circ\varphi_S^{-1}(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \left(\frac{x_i}{x_1^2 + \ldots + x_n^2}\right)_{i=1}^n
$$
is smooth.

However, I can't find the inverse map. If the coordinates are written in the above form (ie $x_i$ over the sum of squares) then it's straightforward, but what if I'm just given $(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Hint: see the pattern starting with $n=2$ and $n=3$

Comment: Isn’t $ \phi_S \circ \phi_N^{-1}$ the inverse?